# Как исправлять ошибки в гугл консоли

Tags: seo

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работает все верно, коды страниц отдаются верно. Если яндекс, то количество страниц что было загружено но не проиндексировано, удаляет самостоятельно. То как это работает в гугл?

Видно, что есть страницы которые отдают 404 код. Необходимо чтобы гугл удалил их, но довольно продолжительное время - 2 месяца, они все еще висят как просканированные.

То есть, как сделать так, чтобы данные страницы гугл удалил из базы, чтобы их количество стало идти на убыль, как это сделать, отправить на проверку? Так они снова вернут 404 код например...

И еще вопрос, почему гугл так же обходит страницы через протокол http? В ответ он получить все равно 301 код на https, для чего он продолжает бегать по протоколу http?

Я не хочу, чтобы гугл тратил усилия и время на обход страниц через http, лучше пусть чаще обходит через https.